# golang read directly from blocks

Tags: linux, file, go, operating-system, filesystems

I have a file of roughly 300MB. and I run the following command on Linux:

`sudo debugfs -R "stat /home/user1/Documents/test.csv"  /dev/sda2`

I get the following output:

```
Inode: 16913580   Type: regular    Mode:  0644   Flags: 0x80000
Generation: 3920968942    Version: 0x00000000:00000001
User:  1000   Group:  1000   Project:     0   Size: 301526706
File ACL: 0
Links: 1   Blockcount: 588928
Fragment:  Address: 0    Number: 0    Size: 0
 ctime: 0x5df9e6c2:7636fdcc -- Wed Dec 18 14:13:46 2019
 atime: 0x5e67b696:d6bfb018 -- Tue Mar 10 21:17:34 2020
 mtime: 0x5df11990:00000000 -- Wed Dec 11 22:00:08 2019
crtime: 0x5df9e6c0:63257940 -- Wed Dec 18 14:13:44 2019
Size of extra inode fields: 32
Inode checksum: 0x35f4d147
EXTENTS:
(ETB0):67695655, (0-8191):162652160-162660351, (8192-40959):165953536-165986303, (40960-57343):165986304-166002687, (57344-61439):166129664-166133759, (61440-65535):166135808-166139903, (65536-67583):166164480-166166527, (67584-71679):166168576-166172671, (71680-73614):166207623-166209557
```

I think the `EXTENTS:` shows the physical blocks of the file.

My question is, is it possible to directly read from these block numbers in golang as byte array?

Comment: You can open `/dev/sda2` as a binary file and seek/read

Comment: if you want to do this kind of thing you should use a log structured storage file system

Answer (score -1):

> My question is, is it possible to directly read from these block numbers in golang as byte array?

No.

Comment: @spiralarchitect It is not supported.

Comment: @Volker A C program running as root can open /dev/sda2 and read and write byte arrays. Why can't a Go program do that?